# Exception when adding formula to an Excel cell using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I've tried a few ways I've seen on here to get this to work but with no success. Most say use .formula or escape characters. I was able to add normal data to cells but I can't add the formula. I know it works outside of Powershell.

Here's the line:

```
$WS.Cells.Item(6,4).formula = "='C:\Users\JG\Desktop\Reference\Financial\Test\[$MNE.xlsx]$MNE'!$O$28"
```

And the error:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC At
>   C:\Users\JG\Desktop\Reference\Test\Test2.ps1:47 char:1
>   + $WS.Cells.Item(6,4).formula = "='C:\Users\JG\Desktop\Reference\ ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to escape the dollar signs in the formula using a backtick - see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6)

Comment: That worked. I was sitting here escaping the single quote. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the `$` in the formula with a backtick `` ` ``, otherwise `$MNE`,`$O` and `$28` are interpreted as variables, with no value. The formula then becomes `='C:\Users\JG\Desktop\Reference\Financial\Test\[.xlsx]'!`, which is invalid.

Your formula then should be:

```
"='C:\Users\JG\Desktop\Reference\Financial\Test\[`$MNE.xlsx]`$MNE'!`$O`$28"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to swap the quotations around. A double quote in PowerShell is a normal string, variables will be expanded when it is eventually interpreted. A single quote in PowerShell is a literal string, no variable expansion can happen inside it.

For example the following $World will be interpreted as a variable and PowerShell will **attempt** to replace it with the $World variable

```
 > Write-Output "Hello $World"
Hello
```

Simply replacing the double quotes with a single quote will stop the variable expansion

```
> Write-Output 'Hello $World'
Hello $World
```

To apply it to your problem you would simply flip the quotations

```
$WS.Cells.Item(6,4).formula = '="C:\Users\JG\Desktop\Reference\Financial\Test\[$MNE.xlsx]$MNE"!$O$28'
```

Useful to keep in mind :)

Comment: Note that Excel still requires the single quotes  within the formula, 1 at the beginning of the path and 1 right after the sheet name. I don't think you can just flip the quotations in this particular case.

Comment: I was a little unsure about how Excel would deal with the double quote. Not useful for this use case but still useful. :)